# SQL sub-queries with no joins

Tags: sql, subquery

I am really struggling with one of the questions while revising. I guess you guys can help me out.

Here I have two tables named book and branch

- [Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awgBX.jpg)
- [Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8CPN.jpg)

The question is:

> List the title and author of books whose sales are greater than the
>   average sales. For each such book, also list the difference between
>   its sales and the average sales. The column of differences in the
>   table of results should be named "Difference".

Here is what I tried

```
SELECT title, authorFROM book
WHERE sales > AVG (sales) ( SELECT bookNo AS Difference
FROM book
WHERE Difference= sales-AVG(sales));
```

Comment: So, you have no idea, no attempt whatsover? We're just to do your homework?

Comment: well i wasn't hoping for that kind of response. I did try. it didnt work for me thats why i posted the question out here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I have added the code which i tried.

Comment: This still seems like a homework question. You don't list what the columns of book and table are.

Comment: Look into the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` functions. Pay close attention to syntax. Also, what DBMS system are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, postgresql, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a table of results with three columns: `title`, `author` and `Difference`(the difference between its sales and the average sales). In sql you can do math in your select expressions, so you can just add `(sales-AVG(sales))` to the list of columns. To specify the name you can use the keyword `AS`.

```
SELECT title, author, (sales-AVG(sales)) AS Difference FROM book WHERE sales>AVG(sales)
```